# Is there a way to allow Windows users to access an XCode Project via GitHub

Tags: swift, xcode, windows, github

I am currently doing a group project for my Computational Physics module at University. The submission must be as an XCode project and using a GitHub Repository. Two of the members of the group (of whom i am not one) have Windows and no access to Swift and XCode subsequently. Is there a way in which they could open and edit the project via an online compiler and return it to GitHub as a commit?

Comment: They need to be able to clone/commit. For the rest, Swift file are just text file, so you can edit them with Notepad++ (if that's still exist), Visual Studio, etc. But it will be harder to compile and check if everything is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. XCode is designed for Apple by Apple, and they understandibly don't want windows users to use it. I would recommend a virtual machine like [VirtualBox.](https://virtualbox.org)